# Java pojo - recycling cached Hashtable values after iterating through new data collection

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable, enumeration, pojo

So yeah, I'm just trying to see if there is a more elegant way of doing what I'm about to do below (please keep in mind that I want POJO (Plain-Old Java Objects) related answers, since this issue is J2ME related, so no Generics and modern data structures only found in Java 1.5 and above):

Suppose I have an object, MyImage, which just a simple bean object that gets populated with data from a network call to my server. All it contains is metadata about said image related to my app, more importantly, it contains a unique identifier that is used to construct a URL in order to fetch the image from my server for that object. I receive a new set of those objects every so often when I make a request for them, some of which are the same as previous requests.

Now, even though I am able to download the image, the problem arises in how to cache the image data in a way that when I receive a new set of MyImage objects, I cross-reference them against my cache and only retain the image for that MyImage object if it was already downloaded. In other words, when I save my downloaded image to my Hashtable cache, I key the image data with the constructed URL (MY_IMAGE_SERVER+myImageUniqueId). When I get a new set of MyImage objects, currently I do the following:

```
 Hashtable imgs = getImages();

 //If we have cached images, we should see which ones to carry over.
 if(imgs.size() > 0){       
    Hashtable newImgs = new Hashtable();
    for(int i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++){
        MyImage mi = myImages[i];
        if(mi != null && mi.hasImage()){
            //Check if we have the MD5 URL
            if(imgs.containsKey(IMG_URL_PATH + mi.getUniqueId())){
                //Place in new hashtable
                newImgs.put(IMG_URL_PATH + mi.getUniqueId(), imgs.get(IMG_URL_PATH + mi.getUniqueId()));
            }
        }
    }
   _bannerImgs = newImgs;
 }
```

I am wondering if this sounds legit, or can it be done in a better more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on the assumed purpose of the code in the comment (below), the way you are doing it seems reasonable, but there are a couple of minor optimization you could make.  Change the relevant part of the code to this:

```
    // Check if we have the image in our cache
    String key = IMG_URL_PATH + mi.getUniqueId();
    Object image = imgs.get(key);
    if (image != null) {
        // Carry over to new cache
        newImgs.put(key, image);
    }
```

Note:

1. Creating / using a local variable avoids creating the key string 3 times.
2. Using `get` instead of `contains` eliminates one hashtable lookup.

However, it is doubtful that this will make a significant difference to your system's performance ... unless the `getUniqueId()` method does something daft, like calculate an MD5 sum each time you call it.  (And apparently it doesn't.)

Notwithstanding the performance, I'd make this change because it makes the code easier to read ... IMO.

Comment: the code is replacing the old cache with a new cache which only contains the images to be retained.  so, it is pruning the old cache.

Comment: FYI, the values for uniqueId are pre-determined and set in stone, all that calculation is done on the backend for each image returned.

Answer (score -1):

if you already had a set containing the keys of images to retain, then you could simply do something like:

```
imgs.keySet().retainAll(stillValidKeys);
```

however, if all you have is a list, then your current code is probably sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, since J2ME/CLDC uses a bare-bones and older version of Java, there is no support for Set objects, so that function won't work for my case.